# How to force copy default for drag-n-drop to a folder on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer, shared-folders, drag-and-drop

As [described here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/move-and-copy-files-using-drag-and-drop), on Windows 7 machines, by default, when you drag a file to another folder on the same drive, it moves the file there.  This can be overridden by holding down the control key on the keyboard before releasing the file, to force a copy.  Similarly, holding down the shift key forces move behavior.

Only for select folders, I would like to change the default to be copy instead of move.  I was thinking I might be able to share the folder and then mount it as a shared folder from myself to trick the OS into defaulting to copy as the shared folder appears to be non-local storage.

Is there a way to configure a specific folder on Windows 7 to default to copy instead of move for local files being dragged to the folder without doing this convoluted solution of sharing a folder with myself?  Can I add a registry entry that overrides this behavior for a specific directory?

Comment: @magicandre1981 That question is for changing the default for the whole, here I'm asking to only change it for a specific directory.

Comment: this makes no difference. Both is the **same** question. There is a link to this MSDN blog which explains why there is no setting: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050609-33/?p=35373/